# How do Movies render text in different languages

Tags: dialogue, production

Normally, when a movie is in English, every Text, every newspaper, etc is in English too. When it comes to dubbing, there is normally subtitles which translate the text, or it's read out loud by someone.
But in some movies, texts in the film depend on the language:

English:
[image]

German:
[image]

But wouldn't the movie makers need to render an entire movie, change the language and render it again? As I think that's not how it works, how do they do that?

Comment: They wouldn't need to render the entire movie just that scene

Comment: Are you referring specifically to animated movies like *Zootopia*? For live-action films, they just swap the props round - a famous example I know off the top of my head is the type-written "All play and no work makes Jack a dull boy" from *The Shining*.

Comment: Still doesn't answer how they do it in animated movies. Zootopia was just a good example in that moment

Comment: The movie isn't rendered all at once, it's done scene by scene.

Comment: For that matter, it's not necessary to render the entire scene at once either.  It's possible to render the everything except the banner (or even just the text on the banner), then render the banner separately and composite the two images together.

Comment: The animation could be rendered with no scene and then for every language a text is added in post production with special effects

Comment: Why wouldn't they re-render the whole movie? After all, while rendering does take some computing power, it is just a small part of the total cost of making the content that needs to be rendered. And I seem to recall that for some movies pretty much *every* scene needs to be re-rendered because they not only change the on-screen text, but they (for some, major translations, not all) also alter the *lip sync animations* of the animated characters speaking.

Comment: Because Such movies can take months to render completely. One frame can take several hours, depending on the detail. Even if there is just one scene in the entire movie, they would need at least some days for this scene to render. And if they do it for every language, they wouldn't finish till the end of time